# Download multiple datafile from the same website in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, download

I need to download the datafiles of each year (only the second semester of each year, "S2/year") from this website: [link here](https://www.idescat.cat/pub/?id=ep&n=9123&lang=en).
Once this is done, is there any way to aggregate the population between 15 and 74 years for each year?

Comment: Hi there, I'm not sure I understand well, but if you download them all into a folder, you could maybe use functions similar to:

```install.packages("data.table")
library(data.table)
filepath <- setwd("<my_working_directory_with_downloaded_files/here")

list_of_files <- dir(filepath,pattern=".csv")
list_of_files <- ("*.csv")

read_data <- function(z){
  dat <- fread(z))
  return(dat[1:(nrow(dat)),])
}

datalist <- lapply(list_of_files, read_data)

my_data <- rbindlist(datalist, use.names = FALSE)```
Or maybe:
```testtest <- fread("*.csv"))```
To upload the files.

Comment: Then maybe use ```subset``` and ```filter``` from ```dplyr``` to select by values of a specific column. Hope this helps further!